# "File not found error" when verifying Quarto installation

Tags: installation, quarto

I installed Quarto 1.0.38, Python 3.10, Julia 1.7.3, Visual Studio Code and the Julia, Quarto & Python extensions on Windows 11 following the instructions in https://quarto.org/docs/computations/julia.html.

When I execute

```
quarto check jupyter
```

to verify the installation it fails with the following:

```
[>] Checking Python 3 installation....OK
Version: 3.10.6
Path: C:/Users/kobus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe
Jupyter: 4.11.1
Kernels: julia-1.5, julia-1.6, julia-1.7, julia-nteract-1.6, python37564bit71e25397c0924940962c87edbb66fd67, python37664bitenvvenvc99749bc487c4692a26d5dcf2b43d743, python38164bitepisodeexplorationcondaeccbc25b1ee04fa69b2d22683300cb44, python3

(-) Checking Jupyter engine render....2022-08-07 21:11:35,237 - traitlets - ERROR - Failed to run command:
  ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python.exe', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpsxg7mwcl.json']
PATH='C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7;;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Quarto\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\AdoptOpenJDK\\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\130\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Calibre2\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Devart\\EntityDeveloper\\Console;C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\\Program Files\\Azure Data Studio\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\120\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\140\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib;;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Devart\\EntityDeveloper\\Console;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\GitHubDesktop\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Azure Data Studio\\bin;C:\\Users\\kobus\\.dotnet\\tools;C:\\Users\\kobus\\.dotnet\\tools;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\kobus\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Quarto\\bin'
with kwargs:
  {'stdin': -1, 'stdout': None, 'stderr': None, 'cwd': None, 'close_fds': False}

2022-08-07 21:11:35,238 - traitlets - ERROR - [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 75, in wrapper
out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 389, in _async_start_kernel
await ensure_async(self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw))
File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 38, in ensure_async
return await obj
File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 307, in _async_launch_kernel
connection_info = await self.provisioner.launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\provisioning\local_provisioner.py", line 204, in launch_kernel
self.process = launch_kernel(cmd, **scrubbed_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 170, in launch_kernel
raise ex
File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 158, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
                    File "C:\Users\kobus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
                    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                                             FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
                                                             
                                                             
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[>] Checking Jupyter engine render....OK
```

I am unable to figure why and fix the installation. Could someone perhaps point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: I would attempt uninstall python and Jupyter, restart your laptop, and attempt to reinstall python and then reinstall Jupyter

Comment: Done that, including re-installing VSCode and Julia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by following the approach described in: [Unexpected Julia path](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/1643)

Doing the following:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

and then

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall <<kernel>>
```

for all the kernels listed.

After that I removed the IJulia package, added it again and built it.